# Need to fix the navigation bar & social links in Weebly site

Tags: html, css, templates, navigation, weebly

I have been toying with the different templates at Weebly and trying to find one fixed nav bar that I can add social links at the top to, but I can't seem to work with any. The social links tend to be out of place.

I have decided to use a current template, but need to fix the current header portion. I have tried adding `position: fixed` to a few areas of the CSS, but it turned out horrendous. The background can be seen along with the scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply this to #header-wrap

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
background: #FFF; //if you want a background on the fixed header.
```

You now have the border on the #page-wrap so if you want to keep that give this div a margin-top.
If you want the border on the fixed header, put it there.

Styling for you nav:

```
#nav-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 47px; 
  z-index: 2;
}

#nav-wrap .container {
   clear: both;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   background: url(theme/saperator.png?1418308200) no-repeat bottom left;
   z-index: 2;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ft44wLym/

Comment: thanks for the quick response, when i did that, it only affected the social links part. the logo and navigation bar are not within the header wrap.. apparently i think the logo and navigation are part of the body... is there anything else i can do or how i can mediate this?

Comment: You could make #nav-wrap fixed to and a top of 47px (header height).

Comment: almost there! THANK YOU! just need to adjust certain layout, by any chance that you know how i can better adjust the layout, maybe make the header - logo+ nav bar area height a little smaller

Comment: Sorry i dont know what you mean by 'adjust the layout, maybe make the header - logo+ nav bar area height a little smaller'

Comment: hi there, managed to play with some of the codings, just left with shifting the header, and possibly making a full white horizontal background for the header.. and also shifting the social icons a little to the right.. can anyone help?

Comment: add width:100% to #header-wrap and:
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 47px;
z-index: 2;
To #nav-wrap then you can remove the fixed pos from the container, is that what you want ?

Comment: wow! magic! ive tried putting width100% before ur comment through different sections over and over but did not manage to arrange anything! okay now, i just need to arrange the navigation bar more to the left - its too far right, and need to arrange the logo slightly more to the left.

Comment: You still did not move the fixed position to the nav-wrap also remove the width:100% from the container. I editted my asnwer with the css for you nav and container

Comment: /* Navigation
-----------*/

#nav-wrap .container {
 clear: both;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 padding-right:50px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 background: url(saperator.png) no-repeat bottom left;
 position: fixed;
top: 47;
z-index: 2;
background: #FFF;
width: 100%;
}

#nav-wrap .container table {
 width:100%;
}

Comment: if i remove the fixed position from the #nav-wrap container, the nav bar does not stick on top already. and im not sure which width 100% to remove

Comment: Use the CSS in the fiddle i added in my answer.

Comment: thank you so much jeroen, u have been a brilliant help!

Comment: You are welcome, side note: it is considered bad practise to use tables when you dont need them check this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: thanks alot for the tip jeroen, will keep that in mind. this was a template already provided by weebly and i thought it would be easier to work from a template than to start from scratch. but really appreciate your input, you dont know how thankful i am. been at it for almost 1.5days! ure a really nice and helpful person, thanks!